# Standard deviation of sampling distribution of mean

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, standard-deviation, mean, standard-error

If we take a sample and calculate the mean, we can calculate the standard deviation for the sampling distribution of the mean using this formula:

$\sigma / \sqrt{n}$

But, how many samples do we need take before the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of the mean is roughly equal to $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$? My simulations suggests we need to take about 30 samples. Anything less than 30 samples and the standard deviation of the sampling distribution of the mean seems to be quite a bit higher than $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: As $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ is a direct result of central limit theorem, I can translate your question into another one, "What is convergence rate of CLT?". If you google latter question, some nice pages will come up that answer your question well. see for example http://mathoverflow.net/questions/157672/convergence-rate-of-the-central-limit-theorem-near-the-center-of-the-distributio or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berry%E2%80%93Esseen_theorem

Comment: @Hamed $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ follows from [basic properties of variance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Basic_properties) (for iid rvs) which would be true whether or not the CLT held --- it doesn't *follow* from the CLT, in fact the CLT *relies on it*.

Comment: luciano - 1. What constitutes "roughly equal" for your purposes? 2. One issue is that  bias in using $s$ to estimate $\sigma$ should yield an [underestimate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) not an overestimate -- e.g. for the normal, $(E(s)/\sigma\,=\, 1 - \frac{1}{4n} - \frac{7}{32n^2} - \frac{19}{128n^3} + O(n^{-4})$). The bias depends on the distribution you start with, of course. Getting the opposite bias is a concern. What did you actually do in your simulation? [In any case, if you only consider a few distributions it may give an indication that doesn't generalize.]

Comment: The other issue, besides bias, is sampling variability, in the estimated standard error, or the "standard error of the standard error", if you will.